# macbook air begining 2015 stuck after change SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, time-machine, ssd

I have a macbook air from begining 2015 with 120Go. I bought a Transcend Jet Drive 250 SSD (480Go). I did a backup from time machine and placed it on an external hard drive. I installed the SSD and I restart the Mac with cmd+R. I selected the restore from time machine and connected to external hard drive. I found the new internal hard drive. I wait for 40 minutes and my mac restarted automatically. But it is stuck on the black screen with the apple and the loading bar at the end.

Do you have any idea about the problem ? Can you tell me what I have to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall macOs. I could reinstall Catalina after deleting the content of my new disk. Then, I did Application/Utility/migration assistant and reload the content of my external disk.